# Why is HashSet size 3 after adding 4 objects?

Tags: java, equality, hashset

I am new to Java so please be gentle!

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class HashTest {

private String str;

public HashTest(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    HashTest h1 = new HashTest("1");
    HashTest h2 = new HashTest("1");
    String s1 = new String("2");
    String s2 = new String("2");

    HashSet<Object> hs = new HashSet<Object>();
    hs.add(h1);
    hs.add(h2);
    hs.add(s1);
    hs.add(s2);

    System.out.print(hs.size());
 }
}
```

Output is 3.

My question is -- why 3 ? One of `h1` and `h2` and one of `s1` and `s2` should be inserted. Since they are using the same thing to determine equality i.e. `String.hashcode` function call.

Comment: I'm getting `2` as output.

Comment: @RohitJain, Sorry I posted the wrong code. Please check again.

Comment: And now the output is obvious. `HashTest` isn't using `String#equals()` and `String#hashCode()`, but the default implementation.

Comment: I had 2 questions. The one I posted earlier and this one. I understood the output of first one (the one I deleted) but not of second(which I posted now). I made a mistake and posted the code of first question.

Comment: @RohitJain, does the compiler write the default implementation? What determines the equality in default implementation? If you are sure of your answer, please don't write it as a comment so I can upvote your answer/accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're checking the equality of the `HashTest` objects by comparing their strings in your `.equals()` method. Since both of your `HashTest` objects have the same string, they are equal. Now, the HashSet object replaces `h1` with `h2`, I believe.

Edit:

Just realized the output is actually `2`. That's because the second `String` added replaces the first as well, since the `.eqauls` method of a `String` object also compares the actual string and not the reference.

Edit 2:

Regarding your updated code where you get `3` as the output, you have not implemented an `equals` method. Therefore, it doesn't compare the actual `str` data member of the `HashTest` objects. Now it compares references and adds both `HashTest` objects since they have different references. So there exists 2 hashtest objects now, and 1 string in your `HashSet` now.

Comment: output is 3. I pasted wrong code initially. Please check again.

Comment: ah so default implementation checks for references? If the answer to this is yes, I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @IanMcGrath Yes, the `Object` class implementation of both the methods are used. The `Object#equals()` methods compares object based on reference value using `==`, and hence it will give `false` for `h1` and `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your HashTest object extends Object (all classes extend Object by default), but not String (actually, you cannot extend String because is a `final class`, so when the HashSet uses equals to check if an element already exists, is `Object.equals()` the one executed, not the String.equals() method.You have to override that method with something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof HashTest) {
        return this.str.equals(((HashTest)o).str);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented equals method in your HashTest class. Becoz of that it is treating both h1 & h2 as different objects and inserting in HashSet.

But in case of String, equals is already implemented. So it will override s1 with s2 because both strings are same only.

size of HashSet = one(h1) + one(h2) + one(s2) = 3